# connection error while connecting to csv file

Tags: c#, .net

I have following code and i got the "Unspecified error" when executed.

```
OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new oleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";    Extended Properties=Text;");
ExcelConnection.Open();
```

Answer (score 2):

For loading csv, consider [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) - fully managed, very fast, and robust. I've used in in numerous projects. More importantly, no messing with OLEDB.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the connetion string is fine, is the csv file already open before the call ? If so close then retry.